# Docker Quickstart Terminal. Unable to start the VM

Tags: docker

After restarting machine and opening the Docker Quickstart Terminal, I get the following error:

```html
Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm default --type headless failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Raw-mode is unavailable courtesy of Hyper-V. (VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:02.064418 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
Looks like something went wrong in step ´Checking status on default´... Press any key to continue...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enable Hyper V as following:

Run a command prompt as administrator and execute:

```
dism /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

reboot and

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Comment: I ran the `dism /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V` in a admin powershell and it asked for reboot. the problem was solved.

Comment: For some cases (including my PC), you will get `Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V is unknown.` when you trying to disable Hyper-V from Powershell. So i run `DISM /Online /Disable-Feature:HypervisorPlatform` instead. After that you can follow other step written here.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to disable Hyper-V.
You can do it from Windows Features option or command line.

Answer (score 2):

```
dism /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V

reboot and

bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

The above answer for me is working.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above in Prakash's advice, this is what worked for me: Go to 'Turn Windows features on & off' in the Control Panel:

[image: tur]

Uncheck 'Windows Hypervisor Platform'

[image]

Reboot and reverse the process, enabling 'Windows Hypervisor Platform.'

Answer (score 1):

After following the answer left by Bub Espinja, these were my steps.

---

Run Powershell/CMD as Administrator and enter

```bsh
dism /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
```

Reboot, then enter

```bsh
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

However, I ran into some difficulty so I came back here and followed an additional step left by Prakash.

---

Go to Control Panel [Category View] -> Programs -> Turn Windows features on or off

Ensure 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' is not checked. Expand 'Hyper-V' and enable 'Hyper-V Platform'

[image: Ensure 'Windows Hypervisor Platform' is not checked. Expand 'Hyper-V' and enable 'Hyper-V Platform']

After rebooting, I was able to run 'Docker Quickstart Terminal' and subsequently `docker run hello-world`.

[image: Demonstration of Result]

Answer (score 0):

i also faced the same problem..you can follow these steps to resolve--

1. open  C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox   edit start file as  `${DOCKER_MACHINE}" create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-no-vtx-check $PROXY_ENV "${VM}`

   when docker toolbox was installed it will be as  `${DOCKER_MACHINE}" create -d virtualbox $PROXY_ENV "${VM}`

   [check image of start file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giK7C.png)
2. run `bcdedit` in powershell as admin mode  if u see hyper vision
   launcher type status OFF then it's fine and if it is AUTO then run
   `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` to change status to OFF
3. Removed all temporary files using key combination `win+R` type `temp` and delete all the files
4. Reboot your machine
5. open dockerquickstart it should work fine.