# i cannot start docker in windows 10pro 64

Tags: docker-compose

Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. Sometimes, such confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
Unable to start the VM: C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm default --type headless failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Raw-mode is unavailable courtesy of Hyper-V. (VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Details: 00:00:08.284942 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
Looks like something went wrong in step ?Checking status on default?... Press any key to continue...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Quickstart Terminal. Unable to start the VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635474/docker-quickstart-terminal-unable-to-start-the-vm)

Comment: i have error, again (((

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple as you think. 

1. Copy the command which one you will execute

2. go task manager

3. go more details

4. go file in top left of the window in task manager

5.run new task

6. paste your command in the open box

7. click on dialog box 
8.ok
your command will execute and it will ask for restart, restart it.